# Time Running out during execution

Tags: c

This is 3rd Problem from Project Euler. What is the biggest prime factor of 600851475143. I've done the program but this number in question being a 12digit number, I had to take the datatype as long long. When I try to execute the program for small number, such as 13195, it works fine but for the desired number it doesn't! I tried running it in various compilers online and also on Cygwin which I use on my PC. But the programs stops going forward after three outputs.

HELP!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long num = 600851475143;
    int i=1,j,k, big=0;
    // printf("\nEnter a number:");
    //scanf("%d",&num);
    while(i<=num)
    {
        k=0;
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            j = 1;
            while( j <= i)
            {
                if( i % j == 0)
                    k++;
                j++;
            }

            if(k==2)
            {
                printf("\n%d is a prime factor",i);
                if( i > big)
                    big = i;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("\nBiggest prime factor is %d", big);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your algorithm? There is a simple solution to the problem but let us know how you are approaching the problem.

Comment: The problem is your algorithm.  Your current algorithm is O(N^2), which for a number that large is going to take forever.  The problem can be solved with a single loop rather than two nested ones.

Comment: @StevenBurnap I used the logic here in this prog from somehwere.. I would like to request you to please provide your logic of how to do it in a single loop..

Comment: The fun (and value) in project euler is solving it yourself.  This one is solvable using a single loop.  As a hint, it can be done without ever explicitly testing if a number is prime.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    long long num = 600851475143LL;
    long long i=1;//It must be the same type for num when was the prime.

    for(i=2;i*i<=num;++i){
        while(num % i ==0){
            num /= i;
        }
    }
    printf("\nBiggest prime factor is %lld", num == 1 ? i - 1 : num);
    return 0;
}
```